# bash: export: `=': not a valid identifier -bash: export: `=': not a valid identifier

Tags: macos, bash, terminal

Upon terminal startup, I get this all the time.

```
Last login: Wed Apr  6 12:40:06 on console
-bash: export: `=': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `=': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `=': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `=': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `=': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `=': not a valid identifier
Mymacs-MacBook-Pro:~ mymac$
```

How do I get rid of this?

From `~/.bashrc`:

```
export TOMCAT_HOME=/Library/Tomcat/Home
export IDP_HOME=/Library/SHIBBOLETH-idp/Home
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_73.jdk/Contents/Home
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export M2_HOME=/Users/app/Applications/apache-maven-3.2.5
export PATH=$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin
export JOSSO2_HOME=/Users/app/Applications/josso-ce
export PATH=$PATH:$JOSSO2_HOME/bin
export ANT_HOME=/usr/local/bin/ant
export PATH=$PATH:$ANT_HOME/bin
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
```

Comment: Please paste the contents of the file `~/.bashrc` (.bashrc file within your home folder).

Comment: Look for `export` lines in your bash startup files and fix the ones with errors.

Comment: export TOMCAT_HOME=/Library/Tomcat/Home
export IDP_HOME=/Library/SHIBBOLETH-idp/Home
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_73.jdk/Contents/Home
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export M2_HOME=/Users/app/Applications/apache-maven-3.2.5
export PATH=$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin
export JOSSO2_HOME=/Users/app/Applications/josso-ce
export PATH=$PATH:$JOSSO2_HOME/bin
export ANT_HOME=/usr/local/bin/ant
export PATH=$PATH:$ANT_HOME/bin
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting

Comment: Please add that information into your question. It's unreadable as a comment.

Comment: Do you have any lines with `export $var=$value` (a `$` on the wrong side of `=`)? You'll also have to check in file sourced from your ~/.bashrc or other bash rc files. This can be reproduced with `unset foo bar; export $foo=$bar`

Comment: I had few lines in between. I removed them. I closed and re opened terminal and I got the same message but on (ttys000). What is ttys000?     Last login: Wed Apr  6 14:09:20 on ttys000
-bash: export: `=': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `=': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `=': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `=': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `=': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `=': not a valid identifier

Comment: I reverted my change. The issue still exists but I'm back on console (not ttys000).

Answer (score 3):

It's likely that you have spaces around equals signs in one of your bash startup scripts.

Have a look in both `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` for lines that start with the word `export`.  (If those don't yield results, also look in `.profile` and bash startup files you might have modified in `/etc/`.)

In particular, look for this form:

```
export foo = bar
```

And remove the spaces around the `=`, making:

```
export foo=bar
```

From an interactive shell, you can see that this sort of construct produces the error you're experiencing:

```
$ export foo = bar
bash: export: `=': not a valid identifier
```

Comment: And my .bash_profile looks like this-----------------------------------------------------export TOMCAT_HOME=/Library/Tomcat/Home
export IDP_HOME=/Library/SHIBBOLETH-idp/Home
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_73.jdk/Contents/Home
[[ -s "$HOME/.profile" ]] && source "$HOME/.profile" # Load the default .profile

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*

source ~/.profile


# MacPorts Installer addition on 2016-03-25_at_09:51:07: adding an appropriate PATH variable for use with MacPorts.

Comment: export PATH="/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH"
# Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.
export M2_HOME=/Users/app/Applications/apache-maven-3.2.5
export PATH=$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin
export JOSSO2_HOME=/Users/app/Applications/josso-ce
export PATH=$PATH:$JOSSO2_HOME/bin
export ANT_HOME=/usr/local/bin/ant
export PATH=$PATH:$ANT_HOME/bin

Comment: @Twin-sis - please don't ever even consider putting stuff like this into a comment. You can see what it does to the formatting.  If it's relevant to your question, add it to your question.

Comment: Thank you! I am not OP but I had the same issue and it was in the .profile file. I was looking in .bashrc.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by deleting everything in ~/.bash_profile and re writing it. Immediately after this operation, I was on ttys000 instead of on console, after restarting my mac, I'm back on console.
And ttys000 is not an issue either. When you open more than one terminal you are on ttys000, ttys001, ttys002 .... etc